# Installing R package plyr, stringr and reshape in Linux

Tags: linux, r, installation, package

I keep getting an error when trying to install R packages on Linux:

```
* installing *source* package âstringrâ ...
** package âstringrâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package âstringrâ
    finding HTML links ... done
    fixed                                   html
    ignore.case                             html
    invert_match                            html
    perl                                    html
    str_c                                   html
    str_count                               html
    str_detect                              html
    str_dup                                 html
    str_extract                             html
    str_extract_all                         html
    str_length                              html
    str_locate                              html
    str_locate_all                          html
    str_match                               html
    str_match_all                           html
    str_pad                                 html
    str_replace                             html
    str_replace_all                         html
    str_split                               html
    str_split_fixed                         html
    str_sub                                 html
    str_sub_replace                         html
    str_trim                                html
    str_wrap                                html
    word                                    html
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (stringr)
Making 'packages.html' ... done

The downloaded source packages are in
        â/tmp/RtmpXwUJhY/downloaded_packagesâ
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  libpixman-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

```
> install.packages("reshape")
Installing package into â/usr/lib64/R/libraryâ
(as âlibâ is unspecified)
```

also installing the dependency âplyrâ

```
trying URL 'http://cran.r-mirror.de/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 384462 bytes (375 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 375 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.r-mirror.de/src/contrib/reshape_0.8.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 38923 bytes (38 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 38 Kb

* installing *source* package âplyrâ ...
** package âplyrâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: R include directory is empty -- perhaps need to install R-devel.rpm or similar
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c loop-apply.c -o loop-apply.o
loop-apply.c:1:15: error: R.h: No such file or directory
loop-apply.c:2:22: error: Rdefines.h: No such file or directory
loop-apply.c:4: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âloop_applyâ
make: *** [loop-apply.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package âplyrâ
* removing â/usr/lib64/R/library/plyrâ
ERROR: dependency âplyrâ is not available for package âreshapeâ
* removing â/usr/lib64/R/library/reshapeâ

The downloaded source packages are in
        â/tmp/RtmpXwUJhY/downloaded_packagesâ
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("reshape") :
  installation of package âplyrâ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("reshape") :
  installation of package âreshapeâ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: do you mean `reshape2`?

Comment: And you've already tried re-installing `R` to see if you can get `R-devel.rpm` or similar?